# Formik + React: How to sum values from setFieldValue

Tags: reactjs, formik

I want to sum the values of `item.${index}.total_price` to get `totalAll`. But I realized setFieldValue has a delay.
**For example:**

***1st sum:***

total_price: 3.00

total_all: 0

***2nd sum:***

total_price: 9.00

total_all: 3.00

---

**what I want:**

***1st sum:***

total_price: 3.00

total_all: 3.00

***2nd sum:***

total_price: 9.00

total_all: 9.00

Before this I've used useState to store the total_price values, but it also has a delay and it cannot dynamically change the total_price if there is changes in an index.

So how should I sum the total_price?